# In iOS, can a UIButton be added by alloc and initWithFrame?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, uibutton

A button can be added by:

```
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 160, 50);
[myButton setTitle:@"click me" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:myButton];
```

but can we go with the `initWithFrame` method:

```
UIButton *myButton2 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 300, 160, 50)];
//myButton2.buttonType = UIButtonTypeRoundedRect;
myButton2.titleLabel.text = @"click me";
[self.view addSubview:myButton2];
```

but line 2 above is commented out because it causes an error for a "read only" property, and with that line commented out, still no button shows up at all... can a UIButton be added if using `initWithFrame` to begin with?

(**update:** I set a yellow background to see the view's area, and found that the label text of button 2 actually shows up as "click me" in white... but touching it has no visual effect... so I wonder how to change code sample 2 to make it work...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course it can.  I got into a little bit of a discussion as to that readonly buttonType property a while back.  The general concensus is that there is neither a safe way, nor a good reason, for anyone to switch the type of a button.  And besides, `+buttonWithType` returns an instance of UIButton just as well as `+Alloc` and `-init` do, so it isn't a problem.

Comment: and buttonWithType is a convenience method so you don't have to worry about releasing it.

Comment: @CodaFi so if I use `initWithFrame`, there is no way to specify a `buttonType`... and even if there is a default, the button won't show up at all using the second code sample in the original question

Comment: It's because it has no content.  Buttons without a title or image don't show up for some reason...  And if push comes to shove, use method one all the time.

Comment: please see update in the question... i see some text... it also seemed that in the past, we can set the buttonType... so in the past, a button can be created that way

Comment: tried... and it shows a rectangular background (strictly 90 degree corner rect, not rounded rect)... and touching the button has no visual feedback

Comment: Hm... Interesting problem.  File a bug report.