# Button Text not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

When I try to post the following code, my app just shows an empty rectangle where the button's text should be. I am a beginner at xcode and I have determined this code from other tutorials.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UILabel *player1 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35, 120,130, 30)];
    [player1 setText:@"Player"];
    player1.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
    player1.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
     player1.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    [self.view addSubview: player1];

    UIButton *score1 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(165, 120, 60, 30)];
    [score1 setTitle:@"0" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    score1.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
    score1.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    [self.view addSubview: score1];


    UILabel *player2 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35, 150, 130, 30)];
    [player2 setText:@"Opponent"];
    player2.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
    player2.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    player2.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    [self.view addSubview: player2];
}
```

Like I said, everything but the text in the button is showing up.

Comment: Someone has the same issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748238/in-ios-can-a-uibutton-be-added-by-alloc-and-initwithframe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why the button looks blank is because its text color is actually white. Just give it a different color and `0` will now show:

```
score1.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
```

[image]

If you don't want to change the button background color, you may want to set the text color:

```
[score1 setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Read [Question: [initWithFrame:frame] vs. [UIButton buttonWithType]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245882/initwithframeframe-vs-uibutton-buttonwithtype), for more about creating a `UIButton` with these different methods.

Comment: Very good, but it is still better to create the button with `buttonWithType:`. That's what it's for. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the way you're creating the button:

```
UIButton *score1 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(165, 120, 60, 30)];
```

That's not how you do it. Do it like this:

```
UIButton *score1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
score1.frame = CGRectMake(165, 120, 60, 30);
```

All will be well after that!

[image]

Comment: Because that's not how you do it. Gosh, I think I said that. :) @WangYudong try it yourself. Run his code. Then change that one line to my code. You will see the difference!